# Problem with Loop Cut (2 faces selected with a cut in the middle)?

Tags: modeling, extrude, loop

on the left it's good because I created extrusions even if I think it's not the right solution but on the right it's impossible to detach the 2 sides

[image]

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here][image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an Ngon on the right side of the object (the second middle edge that does not loop fully around the object is the cause of this.)

You need to select the knife tool
(K) and manually complete the loopcut around the object so that the object is able to recognise and allow loopcuts normally again.

I would suggest watching a tutorial on Ngons and how to fix/prevent them.

Comment: no there's nothing to do I searched and I still don't understand what are the points that appear? when I click on the first one it selects several faces outside :/

Comment: That is caused by duplicate faces.